# Keyword spotter doesn't work well with narrowband speech signal. How to solve it?

Tags: signal-processing, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

Here's what I have:

1. Acoustic model (CMU Sphinx) to be used in a keyword spotter. Trained for speech sampled at 16kHz and performs well. Doesn't perform well when presented with a speech signal sampled at 8kHz or a speech signal with max bandwidth of 4kHz and sample rate = 16kHz.
2. A microphone which only delivers a narrow-band signal. The bandwidth of the signal is max 4kKz. I can set the sample rate (audio driver API) to 16kHz, but the bandwidth remains the same since the underlying
   HW samples at 8kHz. Can't change that!

Here's the result:

The keyword spotter fails when it's presented with a speech signal (sample rate 16kHz) which only has
a bandwidth of 4kHz.

Here's my question:
Would it be reasonable to expect that the keyword spotter will work if I "fake it" by bandwidth 
extending the narrowband signal prior to sending it to the keyword spotter?

What is the simplest BW-extender ? (I'm looking for something which can be implemented fast).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 8khz models, you should use them instead.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English/cmusphinx-en-us-ptm-8khz-5.2.tar.gz